# How to define a function with two struct parameters from two different header files?

Tags: c, function, header

Im using C. I have two header files (H1 & H2) with two different structs(S1 & S2) respectively. I am trying to define a function in H1 that takes S1 & S2 as its parameters. I do not have the flexibility to move around the structs between the header files.

function(S1,S2);

But how can I declare S2 as the second parameter of this function as it is in H2 not H1?

Comment: in H1.h  
#include "H2.h"

Answer (score 3):

You simply include the header file which defines the structure in your c file.

```
#include "H2.h"
```

Answer (score 2):

In H1, have:

```
#ifndef H1_INCLUDED
#define H1_INCLUDED

#include "H2"

extern ... your_function(S1 arg1, S2 arg2);

#endif
```

In fact, if you only need structure pointers, you don't have to include H1 in H2; you can simply write:

```
#ifndef H1_INCLUDED
#define H1_INCLUDED

struct S2;

extern ... your_function(S1 *arg1, S2 *arg2);

#endif
```

The `struct S2;` line says "there is a structure type with tag `S2` and I'm not going to tell you anything more about it".  It is sufficient as long as the code in the header does not need to access members of the structure, which is highly likely, and as long as the functions take pointers to the structure type and not actual copies of the structure type.

See also:

- [Should I use `#include` in headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804486/should-i-use-include-in-headers/)
- [How to link multiple implementation files in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622409/how-to-link-multiple-implementation-files-in-c/)
- [Which part of the C standard allows this code to compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200096/which-part-of-the-c-standard-allows-this-code-to-compile)