# Declaring a struct (that's already been typedef'd) within another struct?

Tags: c, struct, typedef, declaration

My understanding of C is that there are two separate namespaces, one for tags (such as for structs) and one for all other variables (including structs).  Using typedef before a struct definition will then treat the struct variable as a type, so if you use

```
struct car_part {/* Code Here */} CarPart;
```

(where CarPart is optional)
you'd have to use

```
struct car_part engine;
```

to declare a car part.
Whereas if you used a typedef with

```
typedef car_part {/* Code Here */} CarPart;
```

you can now use

```
CarPart engine;
```

instead.

```
typedef struct tag {/* Code here */} struct_name;
```

1)  Is there any difference between declaring the actual variable before or after the block code?  i.e.

```
typedef struct tag struct_name
{
    /* Code here */
};
```

vs

```
typedef struct tag
{
    /* Code here*/
} struct_name;
```

2)  Are there ever any advantages to not using typedef for a struct definition, even if you won't declare another struct variable of that type?

3) The following code says that there's a syntax error C2061 with the identifier Node, but I don't see anything wrong with it.  I tried adding the keyword struct before each element declaration, but that only gave more errors.  Any thoughts?

```
typedef struct Ticket
{
    char customer_name[20];
    int ticket_number;
} Ticket;

typedef struct Node
{
    Ticket ticket_info;
    Node *next;
    Node *previous;
} Node;

typedef struct Queue
{
    Ticket *front;
    Ticket *rear;
    int queue_count;
} Queue;
```

edit: fixed first two lines of code to explicitly state where the element declarations should be.

Comment: I have the habit of naming my `struct` with a `_st` suffix, so `struct node_st { /*fields*/ };`  and `typedef struct node_st Node;`

Comment: Your very first line of code is invalid.  What would you expect `struct car_part CarPart;` to do, in words?  gcc just gives me an error "storage size of 'CarPart' isn't known" when I compile a program where that is the first line.

Comment: @David Sorry, meant to put code between car_part and CarPart like in the other code.  That'd be where the element declaration would go.

Comment: 1) I've never tried it the first way, and I don't commonly do it the second say; I wouldn't really see much of a need either way to have a global struct. I prefer local variables and proper passing/returning. 2) YES! When you start dicking around with ADT's (Abstract Data Types), you'll wish you hadn't typedef'd all of the structs. They behave differently, and sometimes very strangely.

Comment: You can edit the question to make your code valid.

Comment: There are more namespaces than the two you identified, and neither is completely accurately characterized. The first is for tags associated with the `struct`, `union` or `enum` keywords. The other is the 'ordinary identifiers' name space, used by functions, variables and typedef names.  There is also the macro namespace, the label namespace, and each structure or union has its own namespace for members.  See section §6.2.3 Name spaces for identifiers in the C standard.

Comment: Note that you start describing a `typedef`, but your example `struct car_part CarPart;` omits the `typedef` keyword, wrecking your question.  As written, `CarPart` is a variable of the previously defined type `struct car_part`, or you have a syntax error if `struct car_part` has not been defined (but note [Which part of the C standard allows this code to compile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200096/which-part-of-the-c-standard-allows-this-code-to-compile)).

Answer (score 3):

There are actually four name-spaces in C (although this depends on a particular way of counting, and some include macro names as a fifth space, which I think is a valid way to think about them):

- `goto` labels
- tags (`struct`, `union`, and `enum`)
- the actual members of a struct or union type (one per type, hence you could count this as "many" instead of "one" name space)
- all other ("ordinary") identifiers, such as function and variable names and the names made to be synonyms for other types via `typedef`.

While it should (in theory) be possible to have separate spaces for `struct` vs `union`, for instance, C does not, so:

```
struct foo; union foo; /* ERROR */
```

is invalid.  Yet:

```
struct foo { int a, b; };
struct bar { char b; double a; };
```

is just fine, showing that the members of the two different `struct` types are in different name-spaces (so again this makes the count of "4 name-spaces" above suspect :-) ).

All that aside, C has some moderately (and in some ways unnecessarily) complicated, but quite workable in practice, rules for how struct types work.

Each `struct` creates a new type *unless* it refers back to an existing type.  The `struct` keyword may be followed by an identifier, or just an open brace `{`.  If there is just an open brace, the `struct` creates a new type:

```
struct { ... } X; /* variable X has a unique type */
```

If there is an identifier, the compiler must look at the (single) tag name-space to see if that name is already defined.  If not, the `struct` defines a new type:

```
struct blart { ... } X; /* variable X has type <struct newname>, a new type */
```

If the identifier *is* already present, generally this refers back to the existing type:

```
struct blart Y; /* variable Y has the same type as variable X */
```

There is one special exception, though.  If you're in a new scope (such as at the beginning of a function), a "vacuous declaration"—the `struct` keyword, followed by an identifier, followed by a semicolon—"clears out" the previous visible type:

```
void func(void) {
    struct blart; /* get rid of any existing "struct blart" */
    struct blart { char *a; int b; } v;
```

Here `v` has a *new* type, even if `struct blart` was already defined outside `func`.

(This "vacuous declaration" trick is mostly useful in obfuscated code contests. :-) )

If you're *not* at a new scope, a vacuous declaration serves the purpose of declaring that the type exists.  This is mainly useful to work around a different issue, which I will cover in a moment.

```
struct blart;
```

Here `struct blart` alerts you (and the compiler) that there is now a type named "struct blart".  This type is merely *declared*, meaning that the struct type is "incomplete", if `struct blart` has not yet been *defined*.  This type is *defined* (and "complete") if `struct blart` *has* been defined.  So:

```
struct blart { double blartness; };
```

defines it, and then any earlier or later `struct blart`s refer to the same type.

---

Here's why this sort of declaration is useful.  In C, any declaration of an identifier has *scope*.  There are four possible scopes: "file", "block", "prototype", and "function".  The last one (function scope) is exclusively for `goto` labels, so we can ignore it from here on.  That leaves file, block, and prototype scopes.  File scope is a technical term for what most people think of as "global", in contrast with "block scope" which is "local":

```
struct blart { double blartness } X; /* file scope */
void func(void) {
    struct slart { int i; } v; /* block scope */
    ...
}
```

Here `struct blart` has file scope (as does "global" variable `X`), and `struct slart` has block scope (as does "local" variable `v`).

When the block ends, `struct slart` goes away.  You can no longer refer to it by name; a later `struct slart` creates a new and different type, in exactly the same way that a later `int v;` creates a new `v`, and does not refer to the `v` within the block scope inside function `func`.

Alas, the committee that designed the original C standard included (for good reason) one more scope, inside the function prototype, in a way that interacts rather badly with these rules.  If you write a function prototype:

```
void proto(char *name, int value);
```

the identifiers (`name` and `value`) disappear after the closing parenthesis, just as you'd expect—you wouldn't want this to create a block-scope variable called `name`.  Unfortunately, the same happens with `struct`:

```
void proto2(struct ziggy *stardust);
```

The name `stardust` goes away, but so does `struct ziggy`.  If `struct ziggy` did not appear earlier, that new, incomplete type that is created inside the prototype, has now been removed from all human reach.  It can never be completed.  Good C compilers print a warning here.

The solution is to declare the struct—whether complete or not [*]—before writing the prototype:

```
struct ziggy; /* hey compiler: "struct ziggy" has file scope */
void proto2(struct ziggy *stardust);
```

This time, `struct ziggy` has an already-existing, visible declaration to refer back to, so it uses the existing type.

[* In header files, for instance, you often don't know if the header that *defines* the `struct` has been included, but you can *declare* the struct yourself, and then define protoypes that use pointers to it.]

---

Now, as to `typedef`...

The `typedef` keyword is syntactically a storage-class specifier, like `register` and `auto`, but it acts quite weird.  It sets a flag in the compiler that says: "change variable declarations into type-name aliases".

If you write:

```
typedef int TX, TY[3], *TZ;
```

the way that you (and the compiler) can understand this is to start by *removing the `typedef` keyword*.  The result needs to be syntactically valid, and it is:

```
int TX, TY[3], *TZ;
```

This would declare three variables:

- `TX` has type `int`
- `TY` has type "array 3 of `int`"
- `TZ` has type "pointer to `int`"

Now you (and the compiler) put the `typedef` back in, and change "has" to "is another name for":

- `TX` is another name for type `int`
- `TY` is another name for "array 3 of `int`"
- `TZ` is another name for "pointer to `int`"

The `typedef` keyword works with `struct` types in exactly the same way.  **It's the `struct` keyword that creates the new type**; then `typedef` changes the variable declaration(s) from "has type ..." to "is another name for type ...".  So:

```
typedef struct ca ca_t;
```

starts by either creating new type, or referring back to existing type, `struct ca` as usual.  Then, instead of declaring a variable `ca_t` as having type `struct ca`, it declares the name as another name for the type `struct ca`.

If you omit the struct tag name, you are left with only two valid syntactic patterns:

```
typedef struct; /* note: this is pointless */
```

or:

```
typedef struct { char *top_coat; int top_hat; } zz_t, *zz_p_t;
```

Here, `struct {` creates a new type (remember, we said this way back at the beginning!), and then after the closing `}`, the identifiers that would have declared variables, now make type-aliases.  **Again, the type was actually created by the `struct` keyword** (although it hardly matters this time; the typedef-names are now the only ways to refer to the type).

(The reason the first pointless pattern is the way it is, is that without the braces, the first identifier you stick in *is* the struct-tag:

```
typedef struct tag; /* (still pointless) */
```

and thus you haven't omitted the tag after all!)

---

As for the last question, about the syntax error, the problem here is that C is designed as a "single pass" language, where you (and the compiler) never have to look very far forward to find out what something is.  When you attempt something like this:

```
typedef struct list {
    ...
    List *next; /* ERROR */
} List;
```

you've given the compiler too much to digest at once.  It starts by (in effect) ignoring the `typedef` keyword except to set the flag that changes the way variables will be declared.  This leaves you with:

```
struct list {
    ...
    List *next; /* ERROR */
}
```

The name `List` is simply not yet available.  The attempt to use `List *next;` does not work.  Eventually the compiler would reach the "variable declaration" (and because the flag is set, change it to a type-alias instead), but it's too late by then; the error has already occurred.

The solution is the same as with function prototypes: you need a "forward declaration".  The forward declaration will give you an incomplete type, until you finish defining the `struct list` part, but that's OK: C lets you use incomplete types in a number of positions, including when you want to declare a pointer, and including with `typedef` alias-creation.  So:

```
typedef struct list List; /* incomplete type "struct list" */

struct list { /* begin completing "struct list" */
    ...
    List *next; /* use incomplete "struct list", through the type-alias */
}; /* this "}" completes the type "struct list" */
```

This gains relatively little over just writing `struct list` everywhere (it saves a bit of typing, but so what? well, OK, some of us suffer a bit of carpal tunnel / RSI issues :-) ).

---

[Note: this last segment is going to cause controversy... it always does.]

In fact, if you mentally replace `struct` with `type`, C code becomes a whole lot nicer to "strongly typed language" fans.  Instead of the terrible [%], weak-sauce:

```
typedef int distance; /* distance is measured in discrete units */
typedef double temperature; /* temperatures are fractional */
```

they can write:

```
#define TYPE struct

TYPE distance;
TYPE temperature;
```

These, being incomplete types, are truly opaque.  To create or destroy or indeed do *anything* with a distance value you *must* call a function (and—for most variables anyway; there are some exceptions for external identifiers—use pointers, alas):

```
TYPE distance *x = new_distance(initial_value);

increase_distance(x, increment);
use_distance(x);
destroy_distance(x);
```

Nobody can write:

```
*x += 14; /* 3 inches in a dram, 14 ounces in a foot */
```

It simply won't compile.

Those who are a bit less bondage-and-discipline with their type systems can relax the constraints by completing the type:

```
TYPE distance { int v; };
TYPE temperature { double v; };
```

Of course, now "cheaters" can do:

```
TYPE distance x = { 0 };
x.v += 14; /* 735.5 watts in a horsepower */
```

(well, at least that last comment is correct).

[% Not really that terrible, I think.  Some seem to disagree.]

Comment: quite informative particularly the namespace explanation

Answer (score 2):

**1)**  The difference between those two blocks of code is that the first one is invalid syntax, while the second one is good and useful.  I use the second one in order to define a struct and also define a typedef for the struct at the same time.  My code has stuff that looks like this:

```
typedef struct Dog {
  int age, barks;
} Dog;
```

After that line, I can define dogs with `Dog mydog;` or `struct Dog mydog;`.

It's important to understand that the code above is doing two things.  It is defining a type named `struct Dog`, and then it is defining a type named `Dog` that just refers to `struct Dog`.  You could split that into two separate steps like this:

```
struct Dog {
  int age, barks;
};    
typedef struct Dog Dog;
```

**2)** I always use the typedef as shown above in the first block of code and have found no problem with it.  I would say there are no advantages to leaving out the typdef.  Just for the record, if you want to leave out the typedef and only define a struct, then you code would be:

```
struct Dog {
  int age, barks;
};
```

If you do it that way, you can only make new dogs by typing `struct Dog mydog;`; in other words, the name of the type is only `struct Dog` and `Dog` does not name a type.

**3)** The problem is that you are trying to use "Node" inside the definition of "Node".  That would be a circular definition.  You can fix everything by just writing it like this:

```
struct Node;
typedef struct Node
{
    struct Node * next;
    struct Node * previous;
} Node;
```

Comment: There are some stylistic and preference advantages to removing the `typedef` (such as making it clear you are referring to a structure, not an atomic type) but that's about it.

Comment: Struct names always come after the definition in the block, got it.

Answer (score 0):

1) Your first example is invalid syntax. The correct way is this:

```
typedef struct tag {
    /* ... */
} struct_name;
```

2) Using typedefs for structures makes them seem like atomic data types. It also allows for you to make the types opaque (so other code blocks can't see the inside of the structure). Personally, I find typedef-ing of structures to be a very bad habit (since the `struct` identifier helps differentiate structures and typedefs of atomic types).

3) You are trying to use the typedef'd version of the node structure inside itself! You need to use the `struct Node` identifier for the structure when defining it within itself. Like this:

```
typedef struct Node {
    Ticket ticket_info;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *previous;
} Node;
```

Comment: Ah this is what I was looking for.  So structs that are self-referenced with that struct's original definition haven't received the typedef yet?  That'd explain why it was ok to use Ticket in Node, but not Node in itself?

Comment: Yes, because the `typedef` technically happens *after* the structure is defined, so the structure can't use the `typedef` before it is `typedef`'d.

Comment: One (relatively minor) flaw is that "atomic" types are not necessarily atomic after all.  For instance, on some CPUs, a 4 or 8 byte long type (`long`, `long long`, `float`, `double`, etc) is actually made up internally of multiple shorter items, and what appears to be an atomic assignment (double x = y) is not (there are two 4-byte "mov"s that copy y to x, and an interrupt/signal can result in an apparently-impossible value).  Still, I prefer to keep `struct` exposed, in general.

Comment: Well, from the perspective of C, they are atomic. While you can prove they aren't with hacky `union` magic, the way that such data types are arranged in registers isn't really that important in most cases.