# what is "struct <name_1> <name_2>" in c?

Tags: c, object, variables, struct

there is a line in c code:

```
struct name_1 name2;
```

what this line implies?

my understanding about above line is name_1 is the name of the structure and name2 is the object variable. However name_1 should have been defined somewhere, but I could not find the definition of name_1.

so my question is; is there anything like this where we can have an object of a structure which is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Perhaps `name_1` is defined in a system header file, or a header file not directly in your project?

Comment: Note that you could have a definition `struct SomeThing *sommat;` without a definition of the content of `struct SomeThing` in the file — you can have pointers to incomplete types.  However, you cannot define actual variables as in your question — `struct name_1 name_2;` requires a definition of what's in `struct name_1`.

Comment: Also compare with [Which part of the C standard allows this to compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200096/which-part-of-the-c-standard-allows-this-code-to-compile)

Answer (score 2):

At file scope, this is the definition of a variable called `name2` whose type is `struct name_1`.  If there has not been a previous declaration of `struct name_1;` then this line also declares that type.

Being a file scope variable definition with no initializer nor storage class specifier, this is a [tentative definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/extern). Tentative definitions may have incomplete type so long as the type is completed by the end of the file, e.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo bar;

void f();

int main()
{
    printf("%p\n", (void *)&bar);
    f();

    // cannot do this
    // printf("%d\n", bar.x);
}

struct foo { int x; };

void f()
{
    bar.x = 5;
}
```

This sort of code would be uncommon however. If you see `struct foo bar;` in real code it is more likely that `struct foo` was previously defined somewhere that you are overlooking.

Comment: `struct foo bar;
void f()
{
       struct foo foo_1;
       bar = foo_1;
}`

what this implies? I could not find the definition of foo anywhere.

Comment: @rama that code would only work if `struct foo` is defined elsewhere. If the compiler accepts the code it proves there is a definition somwhere. If you are using an IDE to code in then it may be able to find the definition for you.

Comment: @M.M can tentative definitions be there at the local scope?

Comment: ok , I got it , it has been defined somewhere , perhaps I am not able to find .

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya no, they can only be at file scope

Answer (score 0):

Is there a header file (name.h) you have included in your c code? Usually, structure, constant and function declarations are in the header file, which is 'included' (at the top of your c file), and you could then use those structures and constants in your c file without defining them